# Computer code to quickly check equation of motion to first or higher order from action (4D spacetime)

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, software

I derived equations of motion up to first order from a Lagrangian for a scalar field in a 4D spacetime. Now, I would like to cross-check my results. Is there by any chance an application / code /software somewhere around, where I can (simply) plug in my Lagrangian and get the equations of motion to first order for field and metric perturbations? It can be in an abstract (metric-independent) way, that would be fine. I used xAct / xPert in Mathematica, but I want to make sure that the result is correct by checking them with an independent method.

Comment: You can ask at the xAct Google group, someone may help you. https://groups.google.com/g/xact?pli=1

Comment: Thank you very much, @ApolloRa! As I am already using xAct and I'd like to cross-check my results, a truly independent method would be highly appreciated, e.g. a maple script or some fortran or python code or anything else but xAct. :D

Comment: Hi! I am having the same problem, almost no one considers the simple example of the scale field in xAct.. I found something about the REAL scalar field, but I do not understand how to define a COMPLEX scalar field in xACT.. any hint?